# Using try & catch, how can I validate contents within a file

Tags: exception, try-catch

For a university assignment, we have been just been introduced to try and catch exception handling method, and have some assignment work associated with it.
Our task was to create a file that consits of numbers that are added together and display a total.
However, Anything BUT an INTEGER should be ignored wherever it is placed in the file, and should continue. e.g.
5
6
g
10
Should add 5+6+10 and ignore g, but some reason I can't work out how to ignore anything but an INT. Also, I need it so if the first line of the program is g, it is ignored and continues downwards adding all integers.

I am therefore having a hard time trying to get the program to display the content of file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    int numbers = 0;
    int total = 0;
    Scanner fileScan = null;

    try{
    File integers = new File("integers.txt");
    fileScan = new Scanner(integers);
    // Loops through file and adds up

        while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){
                numbers = fileScan.nextInt();
                System.out.println(numbers);        
                total+=numbers;

        }
        //fileScan.next();
    System.out.print("Normal Total: " +total);
        }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.err.println("Missing file try again!");
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ex){
        System.err.print("result through input exception\n");

        //System.out.println(total);
        //total+=numbers;
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException ex){
        System.err.println("Cannot find error");
    }
    finally{

        System.out.println("\nTotal through finally: "+total);
        fileScan.close();
    }

}

}

 AND the file output is:

result through input exception
6
8

Total through finally: 14
```

Comment: If you are trying to ignore the InputMisMatchException (which is firing from reading a String/char), try commenting out the System.err and placing a continue; in there.

Comment: I was yeah, I wanted it to ignore string and read the next int below it, but it says continues cannot be placed outside a loop

Comment: Ok so just comment out the System.err statement and dont bother using the continue.. If this is a runtime exception it should iterate to the next part of the loop

Comment: Hmm still didn't work sadly. It doesn't display the number and display the total..

Comment: Have you uncommented the System.out.println(total) and the total+=numbers? FYI, you should put the total+=numbers before the print statement

Comment: Okay I switched the print statement and total+=numbers, but now it prints out three numbers, but instead of the number after the letter being printed, it prints the number before the letter. so 6 8 (the system takes 8 again) and outputs the wrong result